# Why answer deleted for spam or rudeness

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

There is the (now closed) [question on Christmas greetings](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69126/christmas-greetings-in-german-for-business-contacts). While I can see to close it as a translation request, it can also be argued that it has merrit as cultural expectations differ and play a role for these things. As such translation are more than just a 1:1 translation of a text.

That aside, and be it as it is, I don't quite get why additionally my answer to this question gets deleted with reasons of being spam or rude. Sure, you may disagree with what I wrote and consider it unhelpful - fine, downvote. But spam? Or rude? What guidelines did I miss or cross?

[Christmas greetings in German for business contacts](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/69126/christmas-greetings-in-german-for-business-contacts/69127#69127)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote:

> [Your text is] bordering to satire with the last bullshit-bingo winning business-speak sentence

which I consider to be violating the [code of conduct](https://german.stackexchange.com/conduct), in particular: “No subtle put-downs or unfriendly language.” (And yes, I know what bullshit bingo is.)

Your answer was flagged as *rude or abusive,* presumably because of this. I concurred with this, which caused a deletion as *rude or abusive* (due to my moderator powers; otherwise more flags would have been required).